# How to send a post using golang, replace with this curl command

Tags: http, post, go

[image: There is my code :]

The error is:

> stream error: stream ID 1; REFUSED_STREAM

But the curl command is Ok:

```
curl -H "Content-type: application/json" -X POST -d '{"skip_mobile":false,"selected_website":[],"basic_info":{"name":"王凯","id_card_num":"410881199210130778","cell_phone_num":"18817953402"}}'  https://www.juxinli.com/orgApi/rest/v2/applications/yiqime
```

I want to know why

Comment: Please post the actual code, not a screenshot of it (anyway, isn't it easier to copy and paste some text, rather that taking a screenshot, cutting it, and uploading it?).

Answer (score 1):

I can give you a simple tip. Just try to run your code using **POSTMAN** Tool of chrome. It's an extension. Install it and send request using that and you can generate exact code in any language for that request.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

There is an issue with Go connecting to nginx over HTTP2.

more details here: https://github.com/golang/go/issues/17066

In versions of Go after 1.6, HTTP2 is enabled by default. Disabling it should solve this.

```
http.DefaultClient.Transport = &http.Transport{
TLSNextProto: make(map[string]func(authority string, c *tls.Conn) http.RoundTripper),
}
resp, err := http.DefaultClient.Do(req)
```